# Change data types stored in NSUserDefault with app update

Tags: ios, objective-c, decode

I save some data saved in my app using NSUserDefaults, for example some object with NSNumber properties.

```html
@interface STAccountInfo : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSNumber* is_new_device_verification_enabled;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSNumber* is_new_device_verification_enabled_by_enterprise;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSNumber* is_collab_related_function_restricted;
```

```html
self.is_new_device_verification_enabled = [decoder decodeNumberForKey:@"is_new_device_verification_enabled"];;
```

But my new version needs to update some NSNumber properties to bool type.

```html
@interface STAccountInfo : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,assign)BOOL is_new_device_verification_enabled;
@property(nonatomic,assign)BOOL is_new_device_verification_enabled_by_enterprise;
@property(nonatomic,assign)BOOL is_collab_related_function_restricted;
```

If I try to decode the stored object, the app will throw an exception due to the wrong data type. What should I do in the decoder part?

Here is the current decoding code:

```
self.is_new_device_verification_enabled = [decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"is_new_device_verification_enabled"];
```

Comment: can you post code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use new key names for your new user defaults, then when you launch:

1. Check for the existence of the old keys - if they don't exist then proceed as usual.
2. If they do exist, Migrate the old key values to the new keys (e.g. change '1' to 'YES')
3. Remove the values for the old keys